# Does the number of map tasks spwaned depends on the number of jobnodes?

Tags: mapreduce

The number of map() spawned is equal to the number of 64MB blocks of input data. Suppose we have 2 input files of 1MB size, both the files will be stored in a single block. But when I run my MR program with 1 namenode and 2 jobnodes, I see 2 map() spawned, one for each file. So is this because the system tried to split the job between 2 nodes i.e.,

```
Number of map() spawned = number of 64MB blocks of input data * number of jobnodes ?
```

Also, in the mapreduce tutorial, its written than for a 10TB file with blocksize being 128KB, 82000 maps will be spawned. However, according to the logic that number of maps is only dependent on block size, 78125 jobs must be spawned (10TB/128MB). I am not understanding how few extra jobs have been spawned? It will be great if anyone can share your thoughts on this? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

By Default one mapper per input file is spawned and if the size of input file is greater than than split size(which is normally kept same as block size) then for that file number of mappers will be ceil of filesize/split size.

Now say you 5 input files and split size is kept as 64 MB

```
file1 - 10 MB
file2 - 30 MB
file3 - 50 MB
file4 - 100 MB
file5 - 1500 MB
```

number of mapper launched

```
file1 - 1
file2 - 1
file3 - 1
file4 - 2
file5 - 24
```

total mappers - 29

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, input split size and block size is not always honored. If input file is a gzip, it is not splittable. So if one of the gzip file is 1500mb, it will not be split. It is better to use Block compression with Snappy or LZO along with sequence file format.

Also, input split size is not used if input is HBASE table. In case of HBase table, only to split is to maintain correct region size for the table. If table is not properly distributed, manually split the table into multiple regions.

Answer (score 0):

Number of mappers depends on just one thing, the no of InputSplits created by the `InputFormat` you are using(Default is TextInputFormat which creates splits taking \n as the delimiter). It does not depend on the no. of nodes or the file or the block size(64MB or whatever). It's very good if the split is equal to the block. But this is just an `ideal` situation and `cannot be guaranteed` always. MapReudce framework tries its best to optimise the process. And in this process things like creating just 1 mapper for the entire file happen(if the filesize is less than the block size). Another optimization could be to create lesser number of mappers than the number of splits. `For example` if your file has 20 lines and you are using TextInputFormat then you might think that you'll get 20 mappers(as no. of mappers = no. of splits and TextInputFormat creates splits based on \n). But this does not happen. There will be unwanted overhead in creating 20 mappers for such a small file.

And if the size of a split is greater than the block size, the remaining data is moved in from the other remote block on a different machine in order to gets processed.

About the MapReduce tutorial :

If you have 10TB data, then -
(10*1024*1024)/128 = 81,920 mappers, which almost = 82,000

Hope this clears some of the things.